# django "python manage.py validate" error : unknown command 'validate'

Tags: django, python-3.4

With running this command:

> python manage.py validate

I faced with this error:

> Unknown command: 'validate'

What should I do now?

For more explanations:

- Linux
- Virtualenv
- Python 3.4.3+
- Django (1, 9, 2, 'final', 0)

Comment: Could you post the ouput or `python manage.py`. Which commads are listed?

Answer (score 29):

I think `python manage.py validate` is deprecated since 1.7, you can use `python manage.py check`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#validate

Answer (score 1):

With `python manage.py` these commands are listed:

> Available subcommands:
>
> [auth]
>
> changepassword
>
> createsuperuser
>
> [django]
>
> check
>
> compilemessages
>
> createcachetable
>
> dbshell
>
> diffsettings
>
> dumpdata
>
> flush
>
> inspectdb
>
> loaddata
>
> makemessages
>
> makemigrations
>
> migrate
>
> sendtestemail
>
> shell
>
> showmigrations
>
> sqlflush
>
> sqlmigrate
>
> sqlsequencereset
>
> squashmigrations
>
> startapp
>
> startproject
>
> test
>
> testserver
>
> [sessions]
>
> clearsessions
>
> [staticfiles]
>
> collectstatic
>
> findstatic
>
> runserver

There is no "validate" command in the list.

Comment: "validate" was moved to "check".

Answer (score 0):

With this command:

> pip install Django==1.8.2

the problem will be solved.
**Django==1.9.2** does not support some commands.